# Swap in C++ - best practice

Tags: c++, performance, design-patterns

I have a class having the following structure:

```
class MyClass {
std::string _myField;
constructor
//copy constructor
//assignment operator
}
```

When I create the object I would like to swap the string instead of copying it. Still, this is against best practices.

Therefore, is there any other better solution to achieve this (movement operator)?
Not even if I use a setXXX and I use swap is not a best decision.

I want to achieve the best performances.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: why `use swap is not a best decision` ?

Comment: Can you post some code showing how you want this swapping to work?

Comment: when do you want to achieve best performance? when measuring number of objects created, or least impact on your other code running? You could ofload the string copying to another thread for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For best performance, pass the std::string by value in the constructor and initialize the member variable using the move constructor:

```
MyClass (std::string s) : _myField (std::move(s)) { /* ... */ }
```

[Want Speed? Pass by Value](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/)

PS. The general advice (pattern?) seems to be to always pass by value the sink arguments.

Comment: This won't have the effect of swapping strings. Of course, it isn't clear whether OP actually needs that, but that is the claim.

Comment: OK, if the OP has the weird idea that he/she needs `MyClass (some_string_lvalue)` to always "clear" the lvalue, I'd suggest this intention is made explicit at the point of the call with `MyClass (std::move(some_string_lvalue))`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: it's indistinguishable from swapping strings with `s` :-)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to achieve the best performances.

This is not possible when using `swap`:

swap requires two operands - which obviously is the member variable and the parameter from the c-tor. That is, your member variable needs to be initialized before `swap` is called. This will invoke a few instructions which are strictly not necessary.

In order to construct your instance with a string argument, use @chill's approach. ;)